# PHP passing variable through a form

Tags: php, html

Hey everybody I have been learning PHP for the last few days and have decided to make a test using a form and radio buttons. By using a submit button I have managed to pass the variables to a process test page, which works out the calculations and send it back to the original page. Though I have having problems using the GET request to receive and display the data.
My apologise for the ignorance of this question.

processTest.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$totalScore = 0;

if($_POST['q1'] == "a"){$totalScore += 20;}
if($_POST['q2'] == "c"){$totalScore += 20;}
if($_POST['q3'] == "b"){$totalScore += 20;}
if($_POST['q4'] == "a"){$totalScore += 20;}
if($_POST['q5'] == "c"){$totalScore += 20;}

header("Location: C1L4.php?totalscore = $totalScore");
exit();
?>
```

C1L4.php (where the test originates)

```
<?
$totalScore=$_GET['totalscore'];
echo $totalScore;
?>
```

If possible could someone give me a brief description what i have done wrong with the GET request and why the variable is not defined would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, it might be worth your time at some point to go through the Zend coding standards for PHP. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html

Comment: You don't have to change location to echo the `$totalScore` value to the actual page: simply replace the last two lines of code with echo $totalScore`

Answer (score 4):

Try changing

```
header("Location: C1L4.php?totalscore = $totalScore");
```

to

```
header("Location: C1L4.php?totalscore=$totalScore");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, another lesson learnt to becoming a master developer :)